# matrix times its transpose equals minus identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What would be a good example for a $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^{T}A=-I$?

It would be better if you can give a matrix which has a well-known name (like "rotation matrix" etc).

Thanks!

Comment: No real such matrix exist. Maybe you could come up with a complex one?

Comment: I think if the diagonal of $A$ is the complex number $i$, and other entries are all 0, then such $A$ will satisfies the condition. But that example is a little bit simple...

Answer (score 3):

You can take any real-valued square orthogonal matrix $A$ (e.g. reflection, rotation, any distance preserving linear transformation) and for this matrix $A$ you will have by definition $A^TA = I$. Then multiplying $A$ by $i = \sqrt{-1}$ will give you what you want.

Note also the equivalent definition of a real orthogonal matrix which is perhaps more illuminating: $A$ is orthogonal if and only if the columns of $A$ form an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + c^2 & ab + cd \\ ab + cd & b^2 + d^2 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Taking $b=c=0$ implies $a=d=i$, where $i^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=I$ over any field that has characteristic 2 (i.e. any field with $1=-1$).